# How to update an array inside of a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to update an array inside a mongoose schema with updateOne?

I have one model on my Node.Js application that I've made with mongoose schema.
One of the fields of my schema is an array:

```
guestsNames: []
```

I'm already able to save items inside of this array but I didn't find a way to update the items inside of it.

Here is my whole schema:

```
const screenImageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    company: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        trim: true
    },
    guestsNames: [],
    imageName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    defaultImageName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        default: Date.now,
        require: true
    },
    activated: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Enabled'
    },
    wsType: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Image'
    }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

...and my updateOne method:

```
screenImageSchema.methods.updateOne = function(id, screenImage) {
    const updatedScreenImage = {
        company: screenImage.company,
        guestsNames: screenImage.guests,
        imageName: screenImage.imageName,
        defaultImageName: screenImage.defaultImageName,
        date: screenImage.date,
        activated: screenImage.activated,
        wsType: screenImage.wsType
    }

    ScreenImage.updateOne(id, updatedScreenImage, {new: true});
}
```

The 'screenImage' parameter passed to the function is an object with all information that I need, including an array with all strings for guestsNames (I've already checked if the parameters are being passed correctly to the object and they are). All fields are being updated with this piece of code except the guestsNames field. What am I doing wrong and how can I make the guestsNames array be updated correctly?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update directly your array like this

```
ScreenImage.updateOne(id, { $set : { guestNames : newArray }})
```

You need to use $set to replace the value of a field, see this [mongoDB $set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: Hi @L.Lecherbonnier can you explain why your answer is the right one

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Finally haha Thank you so much for your help @L.Lecherbonnier =)

Answer (score 0):

**try this if it works**

```
screenImageSchema.methods.updateOne = function(id, screenImage) {
const updatedScreenImage = {
    company: screenImage.company,
    guestsNames[0]: screenImage.guests,
    imageName: screenImage.imageName,
    defaultImageName: screenImage.defaultImageName,
    date: screenImage.date,
    activated: screenImage.activated,
    wsType: screenImage.wsType
}
ScreenImage.updateOne(id, updatedScreenImage, {new: true});
```

}

Comment: can you provide what it inside the array?any key value pair ?

Comment: Just strings taken from the user. There is no key value pair.